# Destructuring a nested array without index?

Tags: javascript, json, destructuring

I am struggling a little bit on how to destructure this object. The simplified version of the object is below:

```
serviceRes = {
    data = {
        gamelogs = [
            {
                stats = {
                    ...
                }
            },
            {
                stats = {
                    ...
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I am traversing the gamelogs array to get the data I need from each game. Basically, I am stuck on how to destructure that gamelogs array, reguardless of index. I had a thought to destructure every iteration of the loop but there seemed like a better way exists.

I have tried various versions of something like below with no success.

```
const { offensePlays } = serviceRes.data.gamelogs.stats.miscellaneous
```

If there is any clarification needed about the object or my intended goal here, I can clarify. I tried my best

Comment: You cannot do `gamelogs.stats`, as gamelogs is an array

Comment: And I'm guess most `=` in your example should be `:`. All you need to / can do is : `const { offensePlays } = serviceRes.data.gamelogs[0].stats.miscellaneous`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use destructuring assignment to transform an array of some objects into an array of their properties. Depending on what you need it for, you should either:

-destructure everything you need in the loop (shown with forEach)

```
serviceRes.data.gamelogs.forEach(({stats:{miscellaneous:{offensePlays}}}) => {
  console.log(offensePlays);
});
```

-or, if you need an array of offensePlays, just use `Array#map()`

```
const offensePlays = serviceRes.data.gamelogs.map(log => log.stats.miscellaneous.offensePlays);
console.log(offensePlays.length);
```

Comment: The first suggestion using the forEach loop worked great for me, thanks!